# How to verify text/content in thousands of PDF files

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to verify/assert certain set of text or sentence in each PDF files automatically. I have 1000s of PDF files which needs to be verified whether a specific text/sentence is present in it.

Comment: Use the text extraction of PDFBox or of Apache TIKA (which uses PDFBox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using Apache Lucene and Apache pdfbox.
Please refer to this post: http://www.programming-free.com/2012/11/simple-word-search-in-pdf-files-using.html